# How to remove a part of the content of a div with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a checkbox, I append some content to a div (#item_list)

```
    if(cb_new.prop('checked')) {
        $("#item_list").append("<input type='hidden' name='post[]' value="+ this.value +">");
        
    } else {            
        // ??           
    }
```

When I uncheck the box I want that exact same string to be removed from the div. Keeping all the others that have a different value (this.value).

So for example I could have:

```
<div id="item_list"> 
<input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="102">
<input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="93">
</div>
```

But if I uncheck

```
<input type="checkbox" id="d-102-2" name="d-102" value="102" data-id="d-102">
```

I want :

```
<div id="item_list"> 
<input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="93"> 
</div>
```

If I check it again, I want it back.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please  [post a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Make it easy for us to help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `data` attribute to assign unique id to the checkbox, once it is checked, input element with same `data-uid` is added and once unchecked we remove the input element with same `data-uid`

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cb_new").change(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $("#item_list").append($("<input data-uid='"+$(this).data('uid')+"' type='text' name='post[]' class='newItem' value='" + $(this).val() + "'>"));
      } else {
        $('.newItem[data-uid='+$(this).data('uid')+']').remove();
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_new" data-uid="8080" value="tick Me" name="test"/><label for="test">Tick Me</label>
<div id="item_list" style="border:1px solid tomato">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A vanilla JS solution would look like:

**Updated according to your expanded requirements**.

```
document.querySelector(`#item_list input[value='${this.value}']`).remove();
```

This will query the DOM, find an `input` element, with a `value` attribute whose value is equal to `this.value`, and remove it from the DOM with the `remove()` method.

A more detailed implementation isn't easy to give without having more information.

Comment: that completely removes my checkbox

Comment: inside :
<div id="item_list"></div> I would like to have for example:

<div id="item_list">
<input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="102"><input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="93">
</div>

But if I uncheck <input type="checkbox" id="d-102-2" name="d-102" value="102" data-id="d-102">, I want :

<div id="item_list">
<input type="hidden" name="post[]" value="93">
</div>

If I check it again, I want it back.

Comment: See my updated answer. :)

Comment: I went for the implementation of Nitin. I'm sure that yours would work as well, but his way made me go to bed serenely.

Comment: Fair enough. I would point out that adding more data to the DOM is often not a great idea, if it can be avoided, and by adding the `data-uid` attribute, you're just essentially duplicating the `id` that's already on the element, which could lead to issues if they're both not managed together. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), whenever possible, it'll make you a much better programmer. :)